# Gradle docker fails to build images due to execution order

Tags: docker, gradle, build

I am trying to use gradle docker palantir plugin for building several docker images. One of the images is the base image so it needs to be published first. However, the images are loaded alphabetically by gradle task. Because the images are tagged with the revision number the build fails. 
The error is:

```
manifest for mswifimesh-register.c.ptin.corppt.com:5000/mswifimesh-base:1.0.0-r240 not found
```

How can I define the building order of the gradle dockerPush task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding on buid.gradle:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    dockerPush.dependsOn('docker_base_image:dockerPush')
}
```

This way first is executed the dockerPush task from the base image.